# Can I use a 220v AC rated switch for 220v 120Hz DC?

Tags: relay, ac, dc

so I have this setup:

[image: circuit drawing]
Bridge Rectifier has no Capacitors! So it outputs 120Hz DC
[image: my DC output]

I had this without the bridge rectifier, but then, since it's AC and you only break one side
the current would jump to the ground and short out the fuse.

The Question is, will the relay slowly get fried or will it do just fine? 
Is there something else I should be concerned about?

Comment: If you're building the bridge rectifier yourself, don't use that schematic, it's wrong. Also, 120Hz DC is an oxymoron.

Comment: The premise is incorrect. The heater element should be isolated from its casing so "the current" can't "jump in the ground". So make sure the heater is correctly isolated then delete the bridge.

Comment: @MattYoung
oh yes. no i defenatly did not use this schematic. i wanted to show it because of the Wave Picture.
How would you call it? because it is not like steady DC flow,
it is some kind of wave.

Comment: If all you are doing is running a heater, why do you need the bridge rectifier anyway?  A heater should work fine on AC.

Comment: @BrianDrummond 
yes the drawing is very poor. the container is isolated but the heating element is not, so it shorts trough the water.
most water heater elements are not isolated properly so i might as well use the one i have.

Comment: @tcrosley i want to be able to put my hand inside (see drawing) without getting a shock xD

Comment: Most water heater elements *are* isolated properly. If your's isn't then its broken and a bridge rectifier isn't going to help you ...

Comment: @swisswiss How does using half-rectified AC create less of a shock hazard than full AC?

Comment: @tcrosley my thought was in my example: that it has polarity like normal DC
so if i disconnect the wire with + the circuit is fully disabled. unlike with AC when i only disconnect one wire the other one will short through the water

Comment: Get a double-pole relay and it will disconnect *both* sides of the heater element.

Comment: @pjc50 i tried with 2 relays for each pole and the problem was one was a bit slower and it also tripped the fuse. i guess those double-pole relays are almost in perfect sync, but isn't this a less proper solution than using DC?

Comment: There is *no* configuration of relays or rectifiers that will make your *unsafe, unisolated, broken* water heater safe to use or prevent it from tripping circuit breakers or blowing fuses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let me say that I agree with all the comments made (Matt, Brian et al).

My concern about this question is **safety** - mains voltage can and does kill.

There are good reasons why only fully qualified and trained technicians and engineers should attempt to work with mains voltages in projects. The fact that so many questions are being asked about the comments made above, together with the poor quality of drawing and a fundamental error in drawing a simple bridge rectifier, does not fill me with confidence.

(1) The bridge rectifier you have drawn is wrong and will not work.

[image]

(2) A water heater element is electrically isolated from its metal casing and normally fitted with some form of thermostat (usually a bi-metallic switch) to prevent it getting too hot. The metal casing surrounding the element must be suitably earthed to prevent shock in the case of a fault.

(3) Both DC and AC are able to give electrical shock. At 220V either can be fatal. (*I'm certain we all remember the fate of topsy the elephant -* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topsy_%28elephant%29 )

(4) A simple circuit only requires a **single break** to prevent current flowing. For AC the switch is usually placed in the 'live' wiring as the 'neutral' is considered to be near earth potential. An example of this would be household light switching.

(5) Isolation switching is when the live and neutral lines are both switched off. The first switch to open switches the circuit off. It is not critical that both switches operate at exactly the same time. If you think the supply is shorting through the water then there is a serious (and dangerous) electrical fault.

(6) There is no advantage in rectifying the AC supply to feed a resistive water heating element. Each half cycle will heat the water and the the mass of the water will 'smooth' out the heating effect. It will not make it safer. 
Switching the element on and off is best done at (or near) the zero crossing of the input to reduce surge current. This can be done with a suitably rated opto DIAC/TRIAC (solid state) switch. For example -

[image]

Comment: thanks for your very detailed answer.
i totally understand your safety concerns.

now lets say i will not build this. and we ignore those drawings and false circuits from google image search. i just added those to show you guys the context of my actual question.

my actual question as stated in the title and first question in the post is about AC rated Switches and halfway converted DC.

could you please answer this as well ? :)

Comment: @swisswiss  From a switch's perspective it does not know if it is switching AC or DC. What it experiences is the current flowing and the voltage across the (open) terminals. Ratings for AC takes into account the switch experiences two zero crossings per cycle which tends to extinguish any arcs. However, as you also have two zero crossings per cycle after rectification (but not smoothing) there should be no difference.